# MediaCapture class doesnt have AddVideoEffectAsync method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk

I recently installed Lumia Imaging SDK V3.0 (Win 8.1) on my Windows Phone 8.1 Application project.

more on this package: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521939

I was able to implement "VideoEffect" sample from link below on my project, to show realtime effects on video...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598530.aspx

My problem is that at some point this sample calls

```
        await m_mediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync(videoEffectDefinition, MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
```

as you know `m_mediaCapture` is type of MediaCapture, but my MediaCapture class doesn't have `AddVideoEffectAsync` method! It only has a `AddEffectAsync` method...

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the AddVideoeffectAsync was introduced in Windows 10: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx

Have you considered writing your app on UWP platform? At this point I don't have anything on hand on achieving the same on Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Thanks, Would applications written on UWP platform run on WP 8.1 ?

Comment: No, Win10 is required for UWP

Comment: well I guess I should find another way.. thanks for your answer